# Pandas Python like Excel Cell Lock

Tags: excel, pandas

I’m trying to replicate Excel’s formula.
For example Sum(A$2:A10)..
Thus if I drag it the sum will always start from row 2 to the current row. I have tried using for loop to iterate per row, but it’s very slow. I wonder if there is build in function in pandas?

Comment: I think this question needs more information on what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really easy, suppose you have an excel file like:

my excel file test.xlsx:

```
col1 col2  co
a    10     2
b    13     7
c    11     6
d    23     7
e    22     9
```

if you want to do a cumulative sum on col2, you do:

```
#read excel and put inside dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('e:/test.xlsx')
print(df)
```

output dataframe:

```
     col1 col2  col3
0    a    10     2
1    b    13     7
2    c    11     6
3    d    23     7
4    e    22     9


df['col2_cumsum'] = df['col2'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

output final with new column:

```
  col1  col2  col3  col2_cumsum
0    a    10     2           10
1    b    13     7           23
2    c    11     6           34
3    d    23     7           57
4    e    22     9           79
```

so you have the sum from row 2 to any other row (for col2)

to finish, you can't apply macro excel in an excel file, only excel plays with its macro when the file is opened in Excel